# Why do we use Hough instead of RANSAC in SIFT?

Tags: computer-vision

In his SIFT paper, why did Lowe choose to use a Hough transform rather than
RANSAC to recognize clusters of 3 consistent features? (Note that RANSAC is more efficient in comparison with Hough)

Link to the paper: https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/papers/ijcv04.pdf

Answer (score 1):

As it is mentioned in the [paper](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/papers/ijcv04.pdf):

> Many well-known robust fitting methods, such as RANSAC or
>   Least Median of Squares, perform poorly when the percent of inliers falls much below 50%.
>   Fortunately, much better performance can be obtained by clustering features in pose space
>   using the Hough transform (Hough, 1962; Ballard, 1981; Grimson 1990).

RANSAC only handles a moderate percentage of outliers without cost blowing up while many real problems have a high rate of outliers.